Is there any reason to collect more money after repaying the company's debt?
In Pikmin 2, after you repay the company's debt of 10,000 Pokos, you are tasked with collecting the rest of the uncollected treasures. However, I noticed you can still earn money outside of treasures by collecting defeated enemies in the underground. Since enemies respawn, theoretically you could continue earning money forever even after every treasure has been found.
Does collecting enemies in the underground have any use once you've repaid the company debt? Is there any reason to get more money after reaching 10,000 Pokos?

There is no use for extra money once the debt has been repaid.
The only reasons I found to collect defeated enemies in the underground after paying off the debt were either to fully defeat enemies that can revive themselves if left alone for too long, or to get the bodies out of the way so Pikmin don't try to start carrying them when in a fight.
